# ScrollMagic: setClassToggle() doesn't work with a DOM object as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

setClassToggle() doesn't work with a DOM object as parameter, it only works if the given parameter is a string:

```
// add the class 'myclass' to the element with the id 'my-elem' for the duration of the scene
scene.setClassToggle("#my-elem", "myclass"); // will work
scene.setClassToggle($("#my-elem"), "myclass"); // won't work
```

ScrollMagic docs says that it should work:

> setClassToggle(element, classes) → {Scene}
>
> element   string | object
>
> A Selector targeting one or more elements or a DOM object that is
>   supposed to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing it a DOM object, but rather a JQuery object. Try adding a `[0]` at the end of that selector and see if it works.

```
scene.setClassToggle($("#my-elem")[0], "myclass");
```